# Identity Server Endpoints OIDC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, identityserver3, identityserver4

I am using Identity server and hosting it under IIS. It was working fine when hosted directly under `http://localhost:44431`

**Step 1:** call http://localhost:44431/account/login?returnUrl=/connect/authorize/login?respone_type....
 **Step 2:** Then  it goes to the Authorize Endpoint and a return a token

**Probelm hosting under localhost\id:**

However, when I deploy the application on IIS under Default Web site as `localhost\id`. It stops working.

**Step 1:** Calling  http://localhost/id/account/login?returnUrl=/connect/authorize/login?respone_type....

*>> Inspecting the Request Headers:*

[image]

*>> Response Header:*

[image]

*>> Open Id Configuration at http://localhost/id/.well-known/openid-configuration*

```
  "authorization_endpoint":"http://localhost/id/connect/authorize",
```

**Step 2:** Calling the `/connect/authorize` endpoint:

*>> Inspecting the Headers:*

[image]

It didn't include the `id` virtual directory, that's why it is failing. where in the process I have to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce your problem, but I did start from scratch hosting IdentityServer4 in IIS. The steps I followed for setup are below.

1. Cloned IdentityServer4.Samples. Launch Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication solution:
   https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication
2. Created an application in IIS with the path as '/id' with the AppPool set to 'No Managed Code'
3. Ran 'dotnet publish' on the IdentityServer4 project and moved the output to the IIS app root's folder
4. Changed the Authority URL in the MvcClient project to point to localhost/id

   ```
   app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
   {
       AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
       SignInScheme = "Cookies",
       Authority = "http://localhost/id",
       RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
       ClientId = "mvc",
       SaveTokens = true
   });
   ```
5. Load the MvcClient application and navigate to a route with the 'Authorize' filter. The redirect occurred properly with the appropriate virtual directory

Check to see if the proper path is being output by IdentityServer by going to the openid-configuration page: http://localhost/id/.well-known/openid-configuration

Are you running IdentityServer4 and an MVC app in the same project? If so, are you using relative paths for the OpenIdConnectOptions.Authority property? Try changing it to an absolute path and see if that fixes the problem. I'm thinking this might be the case, because your request URL does not include the /id path in the redirect uri:

```
http://localhost/id/account/login?**returnUrl=/connect/authorize/login**?respone_type
```

The correct path of course should be:

```
http://localhost/id/account/login?**returnUrl=/id/connect/authorize/login**?respone_type
```

Hope this helps! Please let me know

Comment: The Open ID Configuration is fine. I am not using an MVC app in the same project, Its an angular2 project in different application. But I am testing that from URL regardless of the other application, by just placing it in the url. I will try reproduce it again by installing a fresh copy.

Comment: So you're making that URL by hand? If so, then my suggestion at the bottom should resolve it - if you're staying on the same domain, you still need the /I'd at the front. If crossing domains, it needs to be an absolute path including the /id